# Upload many file to Many Model properties in a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, post, file-upload

I have to fill out following model in a view:

```
IEnumerable<File> Photos
IEnumerable<File> Logos
IEnumerable<File> Videos
```

How can send multiple files with one POST to a controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(Class Model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Photos, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Logos, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Videos)
    { 
        // proceed 
    }
```

where Photos, Logos & Videos should names of ur controls (input type file)

Comment: Well, what about the rest of Model? How can I post other properties of the model? Can I avoid to make them all as Action parameters?